# writing an sql query to show names of guests who had both charges?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT GUEST.FIRSTNAME,GUEST.LASTNAME, CHARGETYPE.DESCRIPTION
FROM GUEST
INNER JOIN CHARGES
ON GUEST.GUESTID = CHARGES.GUESTID
INNER JOIN CHARGETYPE
ON  CHARGETYPE.CHARGEID = CHARGES.CHARGEID
WHERE CHARGES.CHARGEID IN ('07','03' );
```

-DEAN       JOHNSON     DINNER SERVICE

-DEAN       JOHNSON     DINNER SERVICE

-JANE       ADAMS       DINNER SERVICE

-PETER      ADAMS       DINNER SERVICE

-PETER      ADAMS       DINNER SERVICE

-JOHN       SMITH       DINNER SERVICE

-JOHN       SMITH       DINNER SERVICE

-DEAN       JOHNSON     ATHLETIC CHARGE

-JOHN       SMITH       ATHLETIC CHARGE

The output should only show that DEAN and JOHN had BOTH athletic and dinner service charges. Is there any easy way to fix this?

Comment: Don't vandalise a post, even your own. Why do you want this to be deleted? [Because it's homework and you want to hide that you got help perhaps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337003/266304)?

Comment: Also [is defacing own posts worth a mod flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306820/is-defacing-own-posts-worth-a-mod-flag)? Sorry, Sparky - once you post it it's gonna *stay* posted. Happy homeworking!

Answer (score 2):

Using `count(distinct col)` in a `having` clause:

```
select 
    guest.firstname
  , guest.lastname
from guest
  inner join charges 
    on guest.guestid = charges.guestid
  inner join chargetype 
    on chargetype.chargeid = charges.chargeid
where charges.chargeid in ('07', '03')
group by
    guest.firstname
  , guest.lastname
having count(distinct charges.chargeid) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

should be pretty straightforward using replicated joins

```
SELECT
  GUEST.FIRSTNAME,
  GUEST.LASTNAME,
  CHARGETYPE.DESCRIPTION
FROM GUEST
INNER JOIN CHARGES
  ON GUEST.GUESTID = CHARGES.GUESTID
INNER JOIN CHARGETYPE c1
  ON c1.CHARGEID = CHARGES.CHARGEID
  and c1.CHARGEID = '07'
INNER JOIN CHARGETYPE c2
  ON c2.CHARGEID = CHARGES.CHARGEID
  and c2.CHARGEID = '03'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a case to this, and if needed you could use this as a sub query to filter down to those that had hadDinner = 1 and isAnAthlete = 1:

```
SELECT GUEST.FIRSTNAME
,GUEST.LASTNAME
, sum(case when CHARGETYPE.DESCRIPTION = 'DINNER SERVICE' then 1 else 0 end) hadDinner
, sum(case when CHARGETYPE.DESCRIPTION = 'ATHLETIC CHARGE' then 1 else 0 end) isAnAthlete
FROM GUEST
INNER JOIN CHARGES
ON GUEST.GUESTID = CHARGES.GUESTID
INNER JOIN CHARGETYPE
ON  CHARGETYPE.CHARGEID = CHARGES.CHARGEID
WHERE CHARGES.CHARGEID IN ('07','03' )
Group by GUEST.FIRSTNAME
,GUEST.LASTNAME;
```